# Showing united border for columns in stacked barchart of chart js on hover?

Tags: chart.js

I have a stacked bar chart. This is the example with one bar:

[image]

What I need is to get a border for all the bar like this:

[image]

I have tried to add border to the dataset, but in this case I get separate borders for every part of the bar:

[image]

**So, the question is, how can I make a united border for the bar?**

Here is my dataset:

```
const datasets = useMemo(() => [
    {
      type:              'line' as ChartType,
      label:             MULTI_BAR_CHART_LINE_NAME,
      data:              data.map(item => item.firstValue),
      fill:              false,
      borderColor:       `${theme`colors.advisor-red-300`}`,
      tension:           0.2,
      pointRadius:       0,
      hoverPointRadius:  0,
    },
    {
      type:               'bar' as ChartType,
      label:              chartLegendLabels.firstLabel,
      data:               data.map(item => item.firstValue),
      backgroundColor:    `${theme`colors.advisor-red-300`}`,
      stack:              'standing costs',
      barPercentage:        0.3,
    },
    {
      type:              'bar' as ChartType,
      label:             chartLegendLabels.secondLabel,
      data:              data.map(item => item.secondValue),
      backgroundColor:   `${theme`colors.advisor-yellow-200`}`,
      stack:             'standing costs',
      barPercentage:     0.3,
    },
    {
      type:              'bar' as ChartType,
      label:             chartLegendLabels.thirdLabel,
      data:              data.map(item => item.thirdValue),
      backgroundColor:   `${theme`colors.advisor-tissue-graph-border-sufficient`}`,
      stack:             'standing costs',
      barPercentage:     0.3,
      hoverBorderRadius: 8,
    },
  ], [data, chartLegendLabels]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it))

All I had to do is add another bar with the transparent background and border on hover

```
{
  type:              'bar' as ChartType,
  label:             '',
  data:              data.map(item => item.thirdValue + item.secondValue + item.firstValue),
  backgroundColor:   `transparent`,
  barPercentage:     0.3,
  hoverBorderRadius: 8,      
  borderColor:       'rgb(153, 102, 255)',
  hoverBorderWidth:  5,
},
```